# Sender name not display when sending emails via Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I am using Mailgun to send mail to my users from Python. Everything works fine except 1 problem. When the user receives the email, it does not show the intended sender name, instead it shows the email which I use to send the email.

Here is the example. In this example, I send an email to my users using the email `support@mydomain.com`. This is what they see in their inbox if I send using Mailgun from Python

[image]

However, if I send email manually from `support@mydomain.com` to my users using Gmail, not Mailgun, the word `support` in the picture will be replaced with the correct name I set up, which is `Kevin from Mydomain.com`. My question is how do I configure Mailgun so that emails sent from Mailgun also show the correct sender name, not the first part of the email I use to send emails (in this case the first part of `support@mydomain.com` is `support`).

Comment: Please show how you you are sending your email ... The simplest is to include the sender name in the API request `curl ... -F from='Sender Bob <sbob@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' ...` (or do the respective with your library)

Comment: your comment works. If you make it an answer I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to include the sender name in the API request

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
  -F from='Sender Bob <sbob@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
  ...
```

(or do the respective with your library)

Comment: Hi, if im using mailgun.js, what is the property i need to add please? @derpirscher

Comment: Hi, I'm using Mailgun too and I'm already setting the "from" property correctly as shown here i.e. from='Sender Bob <bob@domain.com>' but the only email client that's not displaying the name is Outlook. But, I don't believe it's an Outlook issue because I'm not getting this issue when I send emails from Mailchimp for example. I've talked to the Mailgun team in the past with no luck and I just opened a ticket with them as well, I'll update this if they provide a resolution. But, if anyone has an idea how to fix this will be appreciated.